# Alinhamento de celulas no itextsharp

Tags: c#

estou com um problema e não encontro uma solução, estou usando itextesharp em uma aplicação windowsfroms, criei uma tabela com 7 celulas e gostaria de alinhar algumas a direita e outras centralizadas. 
infelizmente só  estou consigo alinhar ou todas as celulas a direita ou a esquerda. atraves da  tabela.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
irei postar o codigo. 
desde já agradeço quem puder ajudar, pois estou precisando muito terminar esse relatório.

```
            PdfPTable tabela = new PdfPTable(7);
            PdfPCell celula = new PdfPCell();
            tabela.TotalWidth = 790f;
            //  celula.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            tabela.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            tabela.LockedWidth = true;
            float[] widths = new float[] { 16F, 40f,45F,60F,15f, 15f, 15f };
            tabela.SetWidths(widths);
            tabela.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            celula.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            strSql= "  ";
            con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strSql, con);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataI", DateTime.Parse(mtbDtInicial.Text));
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataF", DateTime.Parse(mtbDtFinal.Text));
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ifd", emn1);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader ler = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (ler.Read())
            {
                tabela.AddCell (ler[4].ToString()); //conta a direita
                tabela.AddCell(ler[0].ToString());//título  a direita
                tabela.AddCell(ler[1].ToString());//subtitulo a direita
                tabela.AddCell(ler[2].ToString());//descr a direita
                tabela.AddCell(ler[6].ToString());//valor centralizado
                tabela.AddCell(ler[7].ToString());//perce centralizado
                tabela.AddCell(ler[8].ToString());//desp centralizado
            }
            document2.Add(tabela);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sei que é um pouco tarde para a entrega do seu relatório e acredito que você tenha resolvido o seu problema, mas vou deixar essa reposta como auxílio para outros usuários.

Se você adicionar uma `PdfPCell`, o objeto completo, ao invés de apenas seu conteúdo, você consegue definir outras características da célula, como o alinhamento.

```
//Conta a direita
PdfPCell conta_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ler[4].ToString()));
conta_cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT;
tabela.AddCell(conta_cell); 

//título  a direita
PdfPCell titulo_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ler[0].ToString()));
titulo_cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT;
tabela.AddCell(titulo_cell);

...

//percentual centralizado
PdfPCell perce_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ler[7].ToString()));
perce_cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
tabela.AddCell(perce_cell);

...
```